# visual studio c# Web services Soap Comment

Tags: c#

I want to write some comment at the top of the every Method in Web Services that when Clients see they know what should they enter in the fields.

For example in the link below:
http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate

They said for US dollar you should write USD and .....

- AFA-Afghanistan Afghani
- ALL-Albanian Lek
- DZD-Algerian Dinar
- ARS-Argentine Peso
- AWG-Aruba Florin
- AUD-Australian Dollar
- BSD-Bahamian Dollar
- BHD-Bahraini Dinar
- BDT-Bangladesh Taka
- .....
- .....

How can i do the same?

thanks.

Comment: Have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clients shouldn't have to look at a description to know what parameters are required, but here is how to put a description to a method in an `asp.net` web service:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Put your description here")]
```